# Virtuemart 4 installation error

Tags: joomla-4.x, virtuemart

I installed joomla4 latest version **(Joomla_4.2.6-Stable-Full_Package.zip)** and I want to install VM4 **(com_virtuemart.4.0.10.10767_package_or_extract.zip)** and my **PHP version is 8** but the following error occurred on installation:

- Table 'xxxxx_j4-new_db.p8cqq_virtuemart_configs' doesn't exist
- Package Install: There was an error installing an extension: com_virtuemart.4.0.10.10767.zip
- Error installing package

**error image**

[image]

Comment: Have you raised the issue with Virtual Mart support as they are best positioned to diagnose the issue and may have a resolution already,

Comment: Yes I did, but still no answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved in the new version

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question. Could you please be more specific and mention which VirtueMart version (exactly) solved the issue?

Comment: the current version is 4.2.0 and that does not have the mentioned error